# How to call a different database in Magento to fill a custom dropdown box?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, magento

I am extremely new to Magento and I am not sure if what I want is possible. What I am trying to do is not to use the Magento API as we are using a multisite version of enterprise and it is extremely slow. I am currently using Magento version 1.11.

I have a custom module that a previous employee made and I want to add a drop down box for it, have it call a different database (then the one that is setup in the local.xml file) and populate the box on a sql command to get all the Brands from the different database. The different database is a SQL database and not a MySQL database. I know the connection works as I have tested it and when I put

```
mssql_select_db('myDatabase', $link)
die('Something went wrong')
```

it crashes; however, when I put the code like:

```
!mssql_select_db('myDatabase', $link)
die('Something went wrong')
```

it doesn't crash it continues normally.

My SQL code looks like this:

```
$getBrandNameQuery = "SELECT a.BrandID, a.[Name]
FROM mydatabase a
join Categories b on a.CategoryID = b.CategoryID
where a.CategoryID = 1
```

This will give me the brands that I want. Now my php Magento code (though it just gives me a blank page) looks like this:

```
$fieldset->addField("get_brand", "select", array("label"=> $helper->__("Brands"),
"title"=>$helper->__("Brands"),
"name"=>"get_brand",
"required" => true,
/*"values"=> array(
"1" => $helper->__("Active"),
"0" => $helper->__("Inactive"),*/
"values"=> Mage::getSingleton("torus_mailinrebate_block_adminhtml_model_system_config_source_brands")->toOptionArray(),
```

And it doesn't send anything back or populate the drop box. The previous values were 0 and 1 for active and inactive but I am going to have about 30+ items.

My code for getting the data looks like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mssql_num_rows($query); ++$i) {
$row = mssql_fetch_row(mssql_query($getBrandNameQuery));
$id = $row->getId();
$name = $row->getName();
$brandName[] = array('value'=>$id, 'label'=>$name);
}

mssql_free_result($query);
return $brandName;
```

Please tell me where I need to start and any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: your question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821129/magento-make-multiple-database-connections-without-losing-array-values

Comment: I have a connection defined already to a magento DB, but this new connection is for a non magento DB and is meant for read only. I like the link that you provided but how would I add my second DB to the list and where? I don't want any possibility of writing to this new DB at all. I am working with 2 seperate files:
    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\magento2\app\code\local\Torus\MailInRebate\Block\Adminhtml\Rebate\Edit\Tab\Main.php

and

C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\magento2\app\code\local\Torus\MailInRebate\Block\Adminhtml\Model\System\Config\Source\Brands.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to create a new DB connection (which you have already done) and how to access it correctly at the following URL:

http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/create-an-external-database-connection-in-magento.html